# event listener in tic tac toe fields

Tags: javascript, dom, module

I am creating a tic tac toe game that so far has the CSS and HTML ready. I need a function inside the event listener that will inject the board array with an "x" and then an "o" alternatingly till filled and this should also be displayed. the board and the event listener are wrapped inside the module as I am to practice modules

```js
    //player factory function
    const createPlayer = (name,marker) => {
        return {name,marker}
    }

    //gameboard object
    const gameBoard = (() => {
       //create board array
        let board = []
        for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
            board.push("")
        }

        //add event listeners on each field that will mark field
        const fields = document.querySelectorAll(".field") 
        
        fields.forEach((field) => {
            field.addEventListener('click', () => {
                
            })
        })


    })()
```

```css
    :root{
        --blue1: #546482;
        --blue2: #312d44ca;
        --yellow1: #EBEC9A;
        --eggshell: #c5c3c6;
        --header: #bbf0fb;
        --font: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    }

    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        
    }

    body{
        display: grid;
        font-family: var(--font);

    }

    .container{
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .header{
        width: 100vw;
        height: 20vh;
        background-color: var(--blue1);
        border-bottom: 3px solid var(--blue2);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .body-container{
        width: 100vw;
        height: 80vh;
        background-color: var(--eggshell);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content:space-around;
        align-items: center;

    }

    .header-text{
        font-size: 100px;
        color: var(--header);
        font-weight: 550;
    }

    .message{
        font-size: 50px;
    }

    .restart-button{
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-weight: 1000;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        background-color: var(--blue1);
        color: var(--header);
        border: none;
        letter-spacing: 0.8px;
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
        min-width: 130px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .restart-button:hover{
        background-color: #4a5466;
        transition: 0.1s;
    }

    .gameboard{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
        grid-gap: 5px;
    }
    .field{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color:  #ededee;
        
    }

    .field:hover{
        background-color:  rgb(248,248,255);
    }
```

```html
     <div class="body-container">
                <div class="message">Player X's turn</div>
                <div class="gameboard">
                    <div class="field"></div>
                    <div class="field"></div>
                    <div class="field"></div>
                    <div class="field"></div>
                    <div class="field"></div>
                    <div class="field"></div>
                    <div class="field"></div>
                    <div class="field"></div>
                    <div class="field"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="center">
                    <button class="restart-button">Restart</button>
                </div>
       
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Let's go from there. Oh—and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to click on a field, then populate with an X or an O, allowing each player to take turns.

If you want to alternate between X and O each time try this. I'll let you adjust the CSS to make the characters fill the fields.

You'll need to create an event listener for your restart button, but that should just require looping over the fields and setting the innerHTML to an empty string.

```js
 
        
 let turn = 0;
 
 fields.forEach((field) => {

            field.addEventListener('click', () => {
                if(turn % 2) {
                field.innerHTML = "O"}
                else {
                field.innerHTML = "X"}
                turn ++
            })
            
        })
```

Comment: wow that worked. can you explain the percent sign in peusdocode? and also how do i stop the signs from switching when i click again?

Comment: Sure thing, the % sign is division with remainder. When used, it will return the remainder, so if you divide an even number by 2, your remainder will be 0 (a falsy value), and an odd number will return 1 (a truthy value).

For the stopping the signs from switching, I'm assuming you don't want a player to reclick on a field that's already populated? If so, within the event listener, you can wrap everything in another if statement with the condition that field.innerHTML === "". If a field has a value other than "", you will just want the eventlistener to return and not increment turn.